# Assign value from next line in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have data like
Country:
India or Singapore, where you are currently located.

I need to assign "India or Singapore" to variable Country. I am trying to use

`word(mytext[which(str_detect(mytext,"Country"))+1],1:3,sep = fixed(' '))`

but its not able to assign  properly. 
Country and the value are in separate lines
How can I modify my code to assign the proper value.?

Comment: Try `sub("^Country:\\s*([^,]+).*", "\\1", mytext)`

Comment: Its not working, it takes the total document. I just want to read 3 words from the next lines, and assign it to the variable.

Comment: stringr::str_match(text, "Country \\s+(.*)")[, 2]. Its working, but it takes the complete line, I just need 3 words

Comment: Then try `stringr::str_match(text, "Country\\s*([^,]*)")[,2]`. Judging by your example you need all text up to the next comma. Is there a colon after `Country` or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to match all text after `Country:` / `Country` up to the next comma, you may use

```
Country(?:\s*:)?\s*([^,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HZMZ9L/1)

If you know for sure all you need is 3 words after `Country`, use

```
Country(?:\s*:)?\s*([\w'-]+(?:\s+[\w'-]+){2})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HZMZ9L/3).

In R, use `stringr::str_match`:

```
stringr::str_match(text, "Country(?:\\s*:)?\\s*([^,]*)")[,2]
stringr::str_match(text, "Country(?:\\s*:)?\\s*([\\w'-]+(?:\\s+[\\w'-]+){2})")[,2]
```

**Pattern details**

- `Country` - a literal string
- `(?:\s*:)?` - an optional sequence of 0+ whitespaces and then a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^,]*)` - Capturing group #1 matching 0 or more chars other than a comma.

Comment: It is working, but in case if I have to generalize it, like if I need to extract "n" words from the same line, Is there any generic expression? i.e. if I need next 3 words, or 4 words ??

Comment: @SunilRaperia `([\\w'-]+(?:\\s+[\\w'-]+){2})` - 3 words, `([\\w'-]+(?:\\s+[\\w'-]+){3})` -  4 words, etc.

Comment: ([\\w'-]+(?:\\s+[\\w'-]+){n-1}) - n words? If I generalize it?

Comment: Yes, but make sure `n` is more than zero. Also, `(\\w[\\w'-]*(?:\\s+\\w[\\w'-]*){2})` looks safer. `(\\w+(?:['-]\\w+)*(?:\\s+\\w+(?:['-]\\w+)*){2})` is even safer.